# How do I fit my website height to fit the screen?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want my web page to be fit on screen from width and height as well. How is it possible? I know about Media query using widths.

How to set height?

Please tell me How can I use media queries to set my page fit in terms of width and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to be at max width and height for all browsers, do something like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Page content goes here -->
  </div>
</body>
```

And in your CSS put this:

```
.container {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to make the webpage get full width and height and still be responsive.

You need to put the following css.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.the_section_just_after_bodytag {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
```

hope this works.